# MethodInterceptor to retry HttpInvoker call

Tags: java, spring, aop, method-interception

I am using the Spring Framework `HttpInvoker`s on a rich client gui.  Sometimes people have blips in their internet connection and the internet connection failure causes the application to crash.  I would like to retry a failed method a couple times before giving up.

I tried writing a method interceptor to accomplish this but the second call of:

```
Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();
```

always bombs out with a `RuntimeException` wrapping a `NullPointerException`.

Can you not call this method `methodInvocation.proceed()` multiple times or is there some trick to it?

```
public class RetryConnectionTool implements MethodInterceptor
    {
    private static int FailureCount = 0;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RetryConnectionTool.class);
    /**
     * 4 seconds of sleep
     */
    private int SleepTime = 4000;

    public RetryConnectionTool()
        {
        }

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable
        {
        return tryInvoke(methodInvocation, new Integer(0));
        }

    private Object tryInvoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation, Integer tryCount)  throws Throwable
        {
        try
            {
            //if we have failed 10 times in the past or retried 3 times to no success shut it down
            if (FailureCount >= 10 || (tryCount != null && tryCount >= 3))
                {
                logger.error("internet issue failure " + methodInvocation.getMethod().toGenericString());
                System.exit(-1);
                return null;

                }
            if (tryCount != null && tryCount >= 1)
                {
                if (tryCount == 0)   //increment the failure count on every first retry
                    FailureCount++;
                tryCount++;
                Thread.sleep(SleepTime);
                }


            Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();

            //if we have tried more than once and there is already a record of a failure we try again
            if (tryCount != null && tryCount > 1 && FailureCount > 1)
                {
                String messagePassed = "There seems to be a problem with your internet connection.  It the problem persists Iridium Suite will be forced to close.\n" +
                        "Please evaluate your internet connectivity.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messagePassed, "WARNING", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            return result;

            }
        catch (org.springframework.remoting.RemoteConnectFailureException x)
            {
            logger.error("internet issue " + methodInvocation.getMethod().toGenericString(), x);
            //retry on failure
            return tryInvoke(methodInvocation, tryCount);
            }
        catch (RemoteLookupFailureException x)
            {
            logger.error("internet issue " + methodInvocation.getMethod().toGenericString(), x);
            //retry on failure
            return tryInvoke(methodInvocation, tryCount);
            }
        catch (java.net.ConnectException x)
            {
            logger.error("internet issue " + methodInvocation.getMethod().toGenericString(), x);
            //retry on failure
            return tryInvoke(methodInvocation, tryCount);
            }
        catch (RuntimeException x)
            {
            throw x;
            }
        catch (Exception x)
            {
            throw x;
            }
        catch (Throwable x)
            {
            throw x;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question; But Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-api-introduction) recommends you to use AOP using @AspectJ instead of spring's own lower level AOP API. Consider using it.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am using 2.5 which is aspectj anyways.  Any insight on my problem?

Comment: Instead of being "pretty sure" you could just give @AspectJ a try and see what happens. IMO writing a simple pointcut + advice is even much simpler than writing your own interceptor class. If proxy-based Spring AOP is still not enough, you can always resort to full-blown AspectJ via LTW.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `((ProxyMethodInvocation) invocation).invocableClone().proceed();`

proceed can be called only once per MethodInvocation. See [the "Invoking proceed() more than once" section of the "Professional Java Development with the Spring Framework" book.](https://books.google.com/books?id=lt_nh9uJEGgC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=spring+methodinvocation+proceed+more+than+once&source=bl&ots=SMkD8-zxMG&sig=1mEgp0agVb28ezIQz5-SuNwskfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIt8mp9NPTxwIVxNgeCh23nQxJ#v=onepage&q=spring%20methodinvocation%20proceed%20more%20than%20once&f=false)

Comment: We had a similar issue, with `org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method […] on target […] ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` when calling `proceed()` the second time. Using this technique fixed it. This appears to be documented, but only on the [`ReflectiveMethodInvocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ReflectiveMethodInvocation.html) documentation (i.e. the implementation).